# How to set up mouse and keyboard input

Tags: java, input, mouse

Hi I'm trying to program a game using java.  This is my first time using java, I am used to C#.  In C# I would call Mouse.getLocation() and create a rect using the mouses location.  Then by using if(Mouse.Left().toString() == "Pressed") I would then check if the mouse rect intersected with any other objects and act accordingly.

I've noticed in java you aren't provided with methods like these.  So I was wondering, is the best way to approach mouse input simply to add listeners on all my clickable objects?  I understand listeners and have a good idea how to use them but I was just wanting to check if there are more efficient ways to handle input or ways geared more towards what I'm most conformable with.

Comment: When you do eventually write some code, remember to compare strings with the `equals()` method and **not** with `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- let your frame implement the MouseListener interface
- implement all abstract methods, but in your case it is probably the mouseClicked event
- identify if the button clicked is a left click, using the SwingUtilities class
- if it is a left click, then set the x and y, which is the location of your click relative to the frame, not the screen.

  public class MouseListeningObject extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

  int x, y;

  public MouseListeningObject () {
     addMouseListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)){
          x = e.getX();
          y = e.getY();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      // Some codes here
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      // Some codes here
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      // Some codes here
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      // Some codes here
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You want your frame to implement MouseListener then add it in the constructor.

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    MyFrame() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    } 
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```